# RouteParameter error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The error happens here:

```
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

The error I get:

> The type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' exists in both 'z:\Ember.n.SignalR\bin\System.Web.Http.Common.dll' and 'z:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll'

My code:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Ember.n.SignalR
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                //defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to reference

->Right click  on System.Web.Http and get its properties
 ->assign Aliases , example Aliases: MyAlias

now in your code do the changes like this

```
extern alias MyAlias;
using MyAlias.System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

I hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The same assembly is present on two places. The assemblies for asp.net-web api are present in GAC (global assembly cache) because you have installed asp.net mvc-4 that includes this assembly (besides others). You have same dll present in your bin directory. you can try removing the dll from bin and also dereference it from your project if needed.