# Ambiguous reference System.Web.Http.RouteParameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working on MVC5. I just Added a API Controller & facing error in WebApiConfig. The Error is- ambiguous reference system web http routeparameter. I don't understand from where Ambiguity is creating. Can any one please explain??

MyCode is:

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace MyProject
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I am done with the problem. The ambiguity for System.web.http is between System.Web.Http.Common & Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core. I just removed System.Web.Http.Common from my solution as Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core is doing the same stuff for me.

Comment: References, as I told you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. 
If your question it's solved, consider mark it as Answered, to help another people and to avoid keeping it as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

I this this isn't a code issue. It's a project references issue. Delete all the content of your bin folder, check the DLL referenced, and try again. 
Maybe you have two references with System.Web.Routing classes, etc.

Comment: Not worked. Still facing the same error. Till the time I am working on MVC controller. This is the first API Controller I added & facing issue.

Comment: Which are your project's references?

Comment: Apart from default MVC5 libraries Ihave used log4net, Quartz & Mandrill in addition. I search on web & found one link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034626/routeparameter-error. This works for me. But can't get the reason behind error I faced..

Comment: The classes you're using exists on System.Web.Http, System.Web.Mvc, etc.This may be.